# Approach to implementing an STM for a student

Tags: dc.parallel-comp

A student has implemented a scheme interpreter [in scheme](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/) and then [in C](http://nakkaya.com/2010/08/24/a-micro-manual-for-lisp-implemented-in-c/), and a [scheme compiler](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~aghuloum/compilers-tutorial-2006-09-16.pdf) in scheme.

That student is now interested in implementing a STM (Software Transactional Memory) system into this compiler.

Is there a paper/doco to aid them to do this?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a TCS question

Comment: I think I agree with Lev, this seems to be a question about implementations, not theory. But it probably can be rephrased to become a TCS question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look on the wikipedia page for [STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), you'll see that there are many many implementations already available. Many approaches exist and as usual there are always trade-offs to consider. Naturally, associated with these implementations will be technical reports describing their implementations. One approach for scheme is documented in the article *[Reusable building blocks for software transactional memory](http://soft.vub.ac.be/Publications/2009/vub-prog-tr-09-05.pdf)* by Charlotte Herzeel, Pascal Costanza and Theo D’Hondt. This StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627600/how-do-you-implement-software-transactional-memory) also addresses the issue.